# Filter array by select value

Tags: javascript, dictionary, select, filter, filtering

My question is how I can filter array by select value in both situation
For example, I have array with data

```
const array = ['Sarah:cookie', 'Sarah:french fries', 'Sarah:soup',
'John:cookie', 'John:water', 'John:sandwich']
```

I need to create two different select input and handle situation if I choose Sarah I need to display only Sarah dishes.From the different select if I choose cookie, I need to display at the first select input Sarah and John, but if I select water, I need to display only John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

Sarah dishes:

```
array.filter(item => item.match('Sarah:'))
// returns Array(3) [ "Sarah:cookie", "Sarah:french fries", "Sarah:soup" ]
```

Cookie?:

```
array.filter(item => item.match(':cookie'))
// returns Array [ "Sarah:cookie", "John:cookie" ]
```

Water?:

```
array.filter(item => item.match(':water'))
// returns Array [ "John:water" ]
```